# Google Sheets App Script Export to CSV selected Columns

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have this google sheets script which will export my current google sheet to a CSV format in my drive folder.

I tried to select column Index. Ex: columnIndex: 1,2,6,10 But without success, its still export the full data sheet

```
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
    .createMenu('CSV')
    .addItem('Export to the file', 'userActionExportToCSV')
    .addToUi();
}

// https://drive.google.com/file/d/1111111111/view?usp=sharing
var CSV_FILE_ID = '11111111111__8SC0RDV';
var SHEETID = '0';



function userActionExportToCSV() {
  var res = exportToCSV_(
    CSV_FILE_ID,
    SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getId(),
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getSheetId()
  );
  Logger.log(res);
}


  var data = DriveApp.getFileById(csvId)
    .getBlob()
    .getDataAsString();

  // Clear the Sheet
  var updateCellsRequest = Sheets.newUpdateCellsRequest();
  updateCellsRequest.fields = 'userEnteredValue';
  updateCellsRequest.range = { sheetId: sheetId };
  batchUpdateSpreadsheet_(
    {
      updateCells: updateCellsRequest,
    },
    spreadsheetId
  );

  var pasteDataRequest = Sheets.newPasteDataRequest();
  pasteDataRequest.coordinate = {
    sheetId: SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getSheetId(),
    rowIndex: 0,
    columnIndex: 0,
  };
  pasteDataRequest.data = data;
  pasteDataRequest.type = SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES;
  pasteDataRequest.delimiter = ',';

  var batchUpdateSpreadsheetResponse = batchUpdateSpreadsheet_(
    {
      pasteData: pasteDataRequest,
    },
    spreadsheetId
  );
  return batchUpdateSpreadsheetResponse;
}

function exportToCSV_(csvId, spreadsheetId, sheetId) {
  var url = Utilities.formatString(
    'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/export?id=%s&exportFormat=csv&gid=%s',
    spreadsheetId,
    sheetId
  );

  var data = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
    headers: { Authorization: 'Bearer ' + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() },     muteHttpExceptions: true
  }).getBlob();

  DriveApp.getFileById(csvId).setContent(data.getDataAsString());
}

function batchUpdateSpreadsheet_(request, spreadsheetId) {
  var resource = {
    requests: [],
  };
  resource.requests.push(request);
  var batchUpdateSpreadsheetResponse = Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate(
    resource,
    spreadsheetId
  );
  return batchUpdateSpreadsheetResponse;
}
```

I would like to only export some selected columns. By example columns 1,2,6,10.

How I can modify this script to only export the selected columns in my CSV file saved on my Google Drive?

Comment: Your current script just fetches a special URL that displays the sheet as CSV and saves that as a file to Drive. If you want the script to export only some columns, you’ll have to completely rewrite the script to actually get the data from the sheet, filter it to leave only selected columns, and then format it as comma-delimited data and write that to a file. It will be A LOT faster for you to manually select the columns, copy them to a new sheet and the do File->Download as CSV :)

Comment: Agree with the comment above, but would instead have a "export" tab, where a QUERY() lives that looks like this:
=QUERY(Sheet1!A:J,"select A,B,F,J")
then *that* tab is what's exported to csv.